# Dynamic variable in SCSS

Tags: sass, extjs6.5

Hello I want to set the url dynamic based on a variable found in my Application.js. Sof if the variable is true, the path to the url should be like:

```
"https:/asite/resources/mybackground.jpg"
```

Otherwise it takes it directly from the resources folder of the application as such:

```
"/resources/mybackground.jpg"
```

So I need to append the variable in the url. The issue is that the variable is found in my `Application.js` file and not in another scss file.

How can I achieve this?

Please find my css code below:

```
.myviewport::after {
  background: url("/resources/mybackground.jpg") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Can't you change the url with jQuery ? Something like `if(need_change) { $('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'url("the other URL")') }`

Comment: Where to implement this bit of code?

Comment: You can add it in your js file when you getthe variable value !

Comment: I tried it..but does not work. The background image does not show.

I did it in my controller as such:

`init: function() {
        let need_change = true;
        if(need_change) {
            console.log('test');
            $('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'url("/resources/image/mybackground.jpg")  no-repeat');
        }
    }`

Comment: My viewport.js is as follows:

`Ext.define('App.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    controller: 'viewportcontroller',

    requires: [
        'App.ViewportController'
    ],

    cls: 'myviewport',

    xtype: 'myviewport',

    items: [

    ],

});`

Comment: My scss file as follows:
`.myviewport::after {
 // background: url("/resources/mybackground.jpg") no-repeat; //Put in JQuery
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}`

Comment: Is there anything am doing wrong here? Pls have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove the "no-repeat" in jQuery (only `$('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'url("/resources/image/mybackground.jpg"));`) and why your url is `/resources/image/mybackground.jpg` ? In your question it's `/resources/mybackground.jpg`

Comment: Yes the path was a mistype in the question. its "/resources/image/mybackground.jpg" But still does not work.

I have put it in the **init** function is the js file..maybe its at the wrong place?

`init: function() {
        let need_change = true;
        if(need_change) {
            console.log('test');
            $('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'url("/resources/image/mybackground.jpg")');
        }
    }
`

Comment: Did you tried with just `$('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'red');` for example to see if it's jQuery problem or a file path problem ? Can you change the background color / image inside your console ?

Comment: Yes..also tried to see with a afterRender function. Red color does not show. So its issue with JQuery calling?

`afterRender: function() {
        let need_change = true;
        if(need_change) {
            console.log('afterRender');
            $('.myviewport::after').css('background-size', "cover");
            $('.myviewport::after').css('background', 'red');
        }
    }`

The ''myviewport' variable is the xtype of my JS file.

`Ext.define('BORA.view.main.MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
xtype: 'myviewport'
});`

Comment: @MickaëlLeger it works now..your help was previous, it guided me thru. Needed to remove the ***::after*** and it works like a charm.

How to make your comment an answer?

Comment: Cool if it works, I add my comment as an answer :) I was wondering about the `::after`, did you remove it totally ? (just to get it right in my answer)

Comment: Yes I removed it totally and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in jQuery :

```
if(need_change) { 
    $('.myviewport').css('background', 'url("the other URL")') 
}

// else you keep the current background
```